Problem with multiple MQTT messages sent to WiFi MESH_NODE
I am working on a ESP32 MQTT5 WiFi Mesh project using IDF. I am running the same software in my MESH_ROOT as I am in my MESH_NODE both using ESP-32-S3, with a Mosquito broker on a local LAN PC.
I am finding if my client Host (PC App) sends some medium size payloads eg around 420 bytes in quick succession to a MESH_NODE, the first packet is received and responded to by my application, but I don't get a MQTT_EVENT_PUBLISHED event for my response and I don't receive the rest of the published messages.
I can see the response message continues to be resent at 1 second intervals (as we are not getting the Publish Ack from the broker).
Also when this happens I get a matching number of the following messages on my MESH_ROOT
E (13:51:38.630) mesh_netif: Send with err code 16392 ESP_ERR_MESH_ARGUMENT

Eventually my MESH_NODE times out and disconnects from the broker and reconnects after which communications are restored. So its like the Host client MQTT messages overload the MQTT receiver and I lose connection with the broker.
If I add a 200mSec delay between messages published by my client Host app, they are all received and responded to correctly. I don't need this delay when sending to my MESH_ROOT.
I don't mind the 200mS delay, but I am concerned my delays at the Host client app will be washed out by the trip to the broker and then to the ESP32 MESH_ROOT and on to the target ESP32 MESH_NODE
I have streamlined my processing on the MQTT_EVENT_DATA event to simply stack the received message topic, payload, responsetopic and correlationdata into a vector as follows and process it and respond back from another task.
case MQTT_EVENT_DATA: {
        // ESP_LOGD(TAG, "MQTT_EVENT_DATA");
        // print_user_property(event->property->user_property);
        // if (event->property->content_type_len > 0 ) ESP_LOGI(TAG, "content_type: %.*s", event->property->content_type_len, event->property->content_type); // not sure what this is yet
        inBoxClass inBoxrecord = {};
        inBoxrecord.topic.assign(event->topic, event->topic + event->topic_len);
        inBoxrecord.payload.assign(event->data, event->data + event->data_len);
        inBoxrecord.responseTopic.assign(event->property->response_topic, event->property->response_topic + event->property->response_topic_len);
        inBoxrecord.correlationData.assign(event->property->correlation_data, event->property->correlation_data + event->property->correlation_data_len);
        MQTTInBoxMutex.lock();
        inBoxList.push_back(inBoxrecord); // queue into our InBox
        MQTTInBoxMutex.unlock();
        break;
}

Are there some buffers I could increase the size or number of to fix this?
I found esp_wifi_init(&config) the config struct has a number of buffer sounding elements, so I tried increasing the ones which sounded buffer-like and were small as follows:
wifi_init_config_t config = WIFI_INIT_CONFIG_DEFAULT();
    config.tx_hetb_queue_num = 20;
    config.rx_mgmt_buf_num = 20;
    config.cache_tx_buf_num = 20;
    config.static_tx_buf_num = 20;

But this did not help. I also tried increasing the mqtt5_cfg.buffer.size to 10,000 but no change.
Here is a failed run with no inter-message delay. See MQTT_EVENTS event_id=6, my INBOX with the message received, the esp_mqtt_client_enqueue with my response, No MQTT_EVENT_PUBLISHED event. A minute later we log a broker disconnect and reconnect and then everything is restored.
D (13:51:37.875) aMQTT: Event dispatched from event loop base=MQTT_EVENTS, event_id=6
D (13:51:37.877) aMQTT: free heap size is 160648, minimum 155624
D (13:51:37.894) aMQTT: INBOX: Topic: SiteID/00003030F93372B8/Command/Config, Payload: ProtocolPort1=3/ProtocolPort2=4/ProtocolPort3=0/ProtocolPort4=0/StandAloneEntryTime=30/NozzleLiftTimeout=10/NozzleSwapTimeout=5/FuelFlowTimeout=30/PriceChangeTime=10/TransMoneyDecPlaces=2/TransVolumeDecPlaces=2/TransUnitpriceDecPlaces=2/TotalsMoneyDecPlaces=2/TotalsVolumeDecPlaces=2/DensityDecPlaces=1, RespTopic: SiteID/00003030F93372B8/Response/Config, CorData: 677120
D (13:51:38.053) aMQTT: esp_mqtt_client_enqueue successful, msg_id: 4  Topic: SiteID/00003030F93372B8/Response/Config,  Payload: Code=1, CorData: 6:677120
I (13:51:39.872) aMQTT: Task running
I (13:51:39.877) aMQTT: Free Stack NOT used (bytes): 2044
I (13:51:56.892) aMQTT: Task running
I (13:51:56.893) aMQTT: Free Stack NOT used (bytes): 2044
I (13:52:14.069) aMQTT: Task running
I (13:52:14.070) aMQTT: Free Stack NOT used (bytes): 2044
I (107447) mesh: [scan]new scanning time:1500ms, beacon interval:1000ms
I (13:52:31.242) aMQTT: Task running
I (13:52:31.243) aMQTT: Free Stack NOT used (bytes): 2044
E (13:52:48.623) mqtt_client: No PING_RESP, disconnected
D (13:52:48.630) aMQTT: Event dispatched from event loop base=MQTT_EVENTS, event_id=2
D (13:52:48.632) aMQTT: free heap size is 157716, minimum 154932
W (13:52:48.644) aMQTT: Broker disconnected
I (13:52:48.662) aMQTT: App connecting to Broker
I (13:52:48.663) mqtt_client: Client force reconnect requested
D (13:52:48.665) aMQTT: Event dispatched from event loop base=MQTT_EVENTS, event_id=7
D (13:52:48.677) aMQTT: free heap size is 157716, minimum 154932
I (13:52:48.678) aMQTT: Other event id:7
D (13:52:48.730) aMQTT: Event dispatched from event loop base=MQTT_EVENTS, event_id=1
D (13:52:48.732) aMQTT: free heap size is 157292, minimum 153768
W (13:52:48.744) aMQTT: Broker connected
I (13:52:48.746) aMQTT: Resubscribe to our 2 Topics
I (13:52:48.757) aMQTT: Sent subscribe successful, Topic: SiteID/00003030F93372B8/Fuelpoint/+/Command/#  msg_id: 5
I (13:52:48.767) aMQTT: Sent subscribe successful, Topic: SiteID/00003030F93372B8/Command/#  msg_id: 6
I (13:52:48.775) mqtt5_client: MQTT_MSG_TYPE_SUBACK return code is 1
D (13:52:48.778) aMQTT: Event dispatched from event loop base=MQTT_EVENTS, event_id=3
D (13:52:48.790) aMQTT: free heap size is 157052, minimum 151816
I (13:52:48.792) aMQTT: MQTT_EVENT_SUBSCRIBED, msg_id=5
I (13:52:48.808) mqtt5_client: MQTT_MSG_TYPE_SUBACK return code is 1
D (13:52:48.810) aMQTT: Event dispatched from event loop base=MQTT_EVENTS, event_id=3
D (13:52:48.822) aMQTT: free heap size is 157292, minimum 151816
I (13:52:48.823) aMQTT: MQTT_EVENT_SUBSCRIBED, msg_id=6
I (13:52:48.893) aMQTT: Task running
I (13:52:48.895) aMQTT: Free Stack NOT used (bytes): 2044

Here is a successful run with 200ms inter-message delay:
D (13:22:18.245) aMQTT: Event dispatched from event loop base=MQTT_EVENTS, event_id=6
D (13:22:18.246) aMQTT: free heap size is 160592, minimum 156820
D (13:22:18.277) aMQTT: INBOX: Topic: SiteID/00003030F93372B8/Command/DateTime, Payload: 240918132218, RespTopic: SiteID/00003030F93372B8/Response/DateTime, CorData: 266833
I (13:22:18.301) aMQTT: Set system Date: 2024/09/18 Time: 13:22:18
I (13:22:18.000) aMQTT: Set system Date Success
D (13:22:18.095) aMQTT: esp_mqtt_client_enqueue successful, msg_id: 7  Topic: SiteID/00003030F93372B8/Response/DateTime,  Payload: Code=0, CorData: 6:266833
D (13:22:18.986) aMQTT: Event dispatched from event loop base=MQTT_EVENTS, event_id=5
D (13:22:18.987) aMQTT: free heap size is 160592, minimum 156820
D (13:22:18.999) aMQTT: MQTT_EVENT_PUBLISHED, msg_id=7
I (13:22:26.884) aMQTT: Task running
I (13:22:26.885) aMQTT: Free Stack NOT used (bytes): 1996
D (13:22:34.313) aMQTT: Event dispatched from event loop base=MQTT_EVENTS, event_id=6
D (13:22:34.315) aMQTT: free heap size is 160592, minimum 156820
D (13:22:34.330) aMQTT: INBOX: Topic: SiteID/00003030F93372B8/Command/Config, Payload: ProtocolPort1=3/ProtocolPort2=4/ProtocolPort3=0/ProtocolPort4=0/StandAloneEntryTime=30/NozzleLiftTimeout=10/NozzleSwapTimeout=5/FuelFlowTimeout=30/PriceChangeTime=10/TransMoneyDecPlaces=2/TransVolumeDecPlaces=2/TransUnitpriceDecPlaces=2/TotalsMoneyDecPlaces=2/TotalsVolumeDecPlaces=2/DensityDecPlaces=1, RespTopic: SiteID/00003030F93372B8/Response/Config, CorData: 266834
D (13:22:34.349) aMQTT: Event dispatched from event loop base=MQTT_EVENTS, event_id=6
D (13:22:34.370) aMQTT: free heap size is 160204, minimum 156180
D (13:22:34.480) aMQTT: esp_mqtt_client_enqueue successful, msg_id: 8  Topic: SiteID/00003030F93372B8/Response/Config,  Payload: Code=1, CorData: 6:266834
D (13:22:34.513) aMQTT: INBOX: Topic: SiteID/00003030F93372B8/Fuelpoint/1/Command/Config, Payload: ComPortNo=1/PumpIntNo=1/HoseGrade1=1/HoseUnitPrice1=100.1/ProductDensity1=101/HoseGrade2=2/HoseUnitPrice2=100.2/ProductDensity2=102/HoseGrade3=3/HoseUnitPrice3=100.3/ProductDensity3=103/ConfigMiscControls=00FA/TransMoneyDecPlaces=2/TransVolumeDecPlaces=2/UnitPriceDecPlaces=2/TotalsMoneyDecPlaces=2/TotalsVolumeDecPlaces=2/PumpModeSa=0/PumpModeFcc=1/TaggingConfig=0, RespTopic: SiteID/00003030F93372B8/Fuelpoint/1/Response/Config, CorData: 266835
D (13:22:34.516) aMQTT: Event dispatched from event loop base=MQTT_EVENTS, event_id=6
D (13:22:34.565) aMQTT: free heap size is 159996, minimum 156180
D (13:22:34.640) aMQTT: Event dispatched from event loop base=MQTT_EVENTS, event_id=5
D (13:22:34.642) aMQTT: free heap size is 159632, minimum 154428
D (13:22:34.653) aMQTT: MQTT_EVENT_PUBLISHED, msg_id=8
D (13:22:34.664) aMQTT: esp_mqtt_client_enqueue successful, msg_id: 9  Topic: SiteID/00003030F93372B8/Fuelpoint/1/Response/Config,  Payload: Code=1, CorData: 6:266835
D (13:22:34.704) aMQTT: INBOX: Topic: SiteID/00003030F93372B8/Fuelpoint/3/Command/Config, Payload: ComPortNo=1/PumpIntNo=3/HoseGrade1=1/HoseUnitPrice1=100.1/ProductDensity1=101/HoseGrade2=2/HoseUnitPrice2=100.2/ProductDensity2=102/HoseGrade3=3/HoseUnitPrice3=100.3/ProductDensity3=103/ConfigMiscControls=00FA/TransMoneyDecPlaces=2/TransVolumeDecPlaces=2/UnitPriceDecPlaces=2/TotalsMoneyDecPlaces=2/TotalsVolumeDecPlaces=2/PumpModeSa=0/PumpModeFcc=1/TaggingConfig=0, RespTopic: SiteID/00003030F93372B8/Fuelpoint/3/Response/Config, CorData: 266836
D (13:22:34.719) aMQTT: Event dispatched from event loop base=MQTT_EVENTS, event_id=6
D (13:22:34.757) aMQTT: free heap size is 159972, minimum 154428
D (13:22:34.834) aMQTT: Event dispatched from event loop base=MQTT_EVENTS, event_id=5
D (13:22:34.836) aMQTT: free heap size is 159632, minimum 154404
D (13:22:34.847) aMQTT: MQTT_EVENT_PUBLISHED, msg_id=9
D (13:22:34.864) aMQTT: esp_mqtt_client_enqueue successful, msg_id: 10  Topic: SiteID/00003030F93372B8/Fuelpoint/3/Response/Config,  Payload: Code=1, CorData: 6:266836
D (13:22:34.894) aMQTT: INBOX: Topic: SiteID/00003030F93372B8/Fuelpoint/4/Command/Config, Payload: ComPortNo=1/PumpIntNo=4/HoseGrade1=1/HoseUnitPrice1=100.1/ProductDensity1=101/HoseGrade2=2/HoseUnitPrice2=100.2/ProductDensity2=102/HoseGrade3=3/HoseUnitPrice3=100.3/ProductDensity3=103/ConfigMiscControls=00FA/TransMoneyDecPlaces=2/TransVolumeDecPlaces=2/UnitPriceDecPlaces=2/TotalsMoneyDecPlaces=2/TotalsVolumeDecPlaces=2/PumpModeSa=0/PumpModeFcc=1/TaggingConfig=0, RespTopic: SiteID/00003030F93372B8/Fuelpoint/4/Response/Config, CorData: 266837
D (13:22:34.945) aMQTT: Event dispatched from event loop base=MQTT_EVENTS, event_id=6
D (13:22:34.970) aMQTT: free heap size is 159972, minimum 154404
D (13:22:35.046) aMQTT: Event dispatched from event loop base=MQTT_EVENTS, event_id=5
D (13:22:35.048) aMQTT: free heap size is 159632, minimum 154404
D (13:22:35.060) aMQTT: MQTT_EVENT_PUBLISHED, msg_id=10
D (13:22:35.074) aMQTT: esp_mqtt_client_enqueue successful, msg_id: 11  Topic: SiteID/00003030F93372B8/Fuelpoint/4/Response/Config,  Payload: Code=1, CorData: 6:266837
D (13:22:35.114) aMQTT: INBOX: Topic: SiteID/00003030F93372B8/Fuelpoint/5/Command/Config, Payload: ComPortNo=1/PumpIntNo=5/HoseGrade1=1/HoseUnitPrice1=100.1/ProductDensity1=101/HoseGrade2=2/HoseUnitPrice2=100.2/ProductDensity2=102/HoseGrade3=3/HoseUnitPrice3=100.3/ProductDensity3=103/ConfigMiscControls=00FA/TransMoneyDecPlaces=2/TransVolumeDecPlaces=2/UnitPriceDecPlaces=2/TotalsMoneyDecPlaces=2/TotalsVolumeDecPlaces=2/PumpModeSa=0/PumpModeFcc=1/TaggingConfig=0, RespTopic: SiteID/00003030F93372B8/Fuelpoint/5/Response/Config, CorData: 266838
D (13:22:35.191) aMQTT: Event dispatched from event loop base=MQTT_EVENTS, event_id=6
D (13:22:35.193) aMQTT: free heap size is 159972, minimum 154404
D (13:22:35.275) aMQTT: Event dispatched from event loop base=MQTT_EVENTS, event_id=5
D (13:22:35.277) aMQTT: free heap size is 159632, minimum 154404
D (13:22:35.288) aMQTT: MQTT_EVENT_PUBLISHED, msg_id=11
D (13:22:35.294) aMQTT: esp_mqtt_client_enqueue successful, msg_id: 12  Topic: SiteID/00003030F93372B8/Fuelpoint/5/Response/Config,  Payload: Code=1, CorData: 6:266838
D (13:22:35.334) aMQTT: INBOX: Topic: SiteID/00003030F93372B8/Fuelpoint/6/Command/Config, Payload: ComPortNo=1/PumpIntNo=6/HoseGrade1=1/HoseUnitPrice1=100.1/ProductDensity1=101/HoseGrade2=2/HoseUnitPrice2=100.2/ProductDensity2=102/HoseGrade3=3/HoseUnitPrice3=100.3/ProductDensity3=103/ConfigMiscControls=00FA/TransMoneyDecPlaces=2/TransVolumeDecPlaces=2/UnitPriceDecPlaces=2/TotalsMoneyDecPlaces=2/TotalsVolumeDecPlaces=2/PumpModeSa=0/PumpModeFcc=1/TaggingConfig=0, RespTopic: SiteID/00003030F93372B8/Fuelpoint/6/Response/Config, CorData: 266839
D (13:22:35.443) aMQTT: Event dispatched from event loop base=MQTT_EVENTS, event_id=6
D (13:22:35.444) aMQTT: free heap size is 159972, minimum 154404
D (13:22:35.503) aMQTT: esp_mqtt_client_enqueue successful, msg_id: 13  Topic: SiteID/00003030F93372B8/Fuelpoint/6/Response/Config,  Payload: Code=1, CorData: 6:266839
D (13:22:35.538) aMQTT: INBOX: Topic: SiteID/00003030F93372B8/Fuelpoint/7/Command/Config, Payload: ComPortNo=1/PumpIntNo=7/HoseGrade1=1/HoseUnitPrice1=100.1/ProductDensity1=101/HoseGrade2=2/HoseUnitPrice2=100.2/ProductDensity2=102/HoseGrade3=3/HoseUnitPrice3=100.3/ProductDensity3=103/ConfigMiscControls=00FA/TransMoneyDecPlaces=2/TransVolumeDecPlaces=2/UnitPriceDecPlaces=2/TotalsMoneyDecPlaces=2/TotalsVolumeDecPlaces=2/PumpModeSa=0/PumpModeFcc=1/TaggingConfig=0, RespTopic: SiteID/00003030F93372B8/Fuelpoint/7/Response/Config, CorData: 266840
D (13:22:35.549) aMQTT: Event dispatched from event loop base=MQTT_EVENTS, event_id=6
D (13:22:35.590) aMQTT: free heap size is 159800, minimum 154272
D (13:22:35.602) aMQTT: Event dispatched from event loop base=MQTT_EVENTS, event_id=5
D (13:22:35.603) aMQTT: free heap size is 156372, minimum 154272
D (13:22:35.615) aMQTT: MQTT_EVENT_PUBLISHED, msg_id=12
D (13:22:35.672) aMQTT: Event dispatched from event loop base=MQTT_EVENTS, event_id=5
D (13:22:35.673) aMQTT: free heap size is 159624, minimum 154272
D (13:22:35.685) aMQTT: MQTT_EVENT_PUBLISHED, msg_id=13
D (13:22:35.688) aMQTT: esp_mqtt_client_enqueue successful, msg_id: 14  Topic: SiteID/00003030F93372B8/Fuelpoint/7/Response/Config,  Payload: Code=1, CorData: 6:266840
D (13:22:35.724) aMQTT: INBOX: Topic: SiteID/00003030F93372B8/Fuelpoint/8/Command/Config, Payload: ComPortNo=1/PumpIntNo=8/HoseGrade1=1/HoseUnitPrice1=100.1/ProductDensity1=101/HoseGrade2=2/HoseUnitPrice2=100.2/ProductDensity2=102/HoseGrade3=3/HoseUnitPrice3=100.3/ProductDensity3=103/ConfigMiscControls=00FA/TransMoneyDecPlaces=2/TransVolumeDecPlaces=2/UnitPriceDecPlaces=2/TotalsMoneyDecPlaces=2/TotalsVolumeDecPlaces=2/PumpModeSa=0/PumpModeFcc=1/TaggingConfig=0, RespTopic: SiteID/00003030F93372B8/Fuelpoint/8/Response/Config, CorData: 266841
D (13:22:35.738) aMQTT: Event dispatched from event loop base=MQTT_EVENTS, event_id=6
D (13:22:35.776) aMQTT: free heap size is 159960, minimum 154272
D (13:22:35.860) aMQTT: Event dispatched from event loop base=MQTT_EVENTS, event_id=5
D (13:22:35.861) aMQTT: free heap size is 159632, minimum 154272
D (13:22:35.873) aMQTT: MQTT_EVENT_PUBLISHED, msg_id=14
D (13:22:35.880) aMQTT: esp_mqtt_client_enqueue successful, msg_id: 15  Topic: SiteID/00003030F93372B8/Fuelpoint/8/Response/Config,  Payload: Code=1, CorData: 6:266841
D (13:22:35.913) aMQTT: INBOX: Topic: SiteID/00003030F93372B8/Fuelpoint/9/Command/Config, Payload: ComPortNo=1/PumpIntNo=9/HoseGrade1=1/HoseUnitPrice1=100.1/ProductDensity1=101/HoseGrade2=2/HoseUnitPrice2=100.2/ProductDensity2=102/HoseGrade3=3/HoseUnitPrice3=100.3/ProductDensity3=103/ConfigMiscControls=00FA/TransMoneyDecPlaces=2/TransVolumeDecPlaces=2/UnitPriceDecPlaces=2/TotalsMoneyDecPlaces=2/TotalsVolumeDecPlaces=2/PumpModeSa=0/PumpModeFcc=1/TaggingConfig=0, RespTopic: SiteID/00003030F93372B8/Fuelpoint/9/Response/Config, CorData: 266842
D (13:22:35.948) aMQTT: Event dispatched from event loop base=MQTT_EVENTS, event_id=6
D (13:22:35.963) aMQTT: free heap size is 159960, minimum 154272
D (13:22:36.050) aMQTT: Event dispatched from event loop base=MQTT_EVENTS, event_id=5
D (13:22:36.051) aMQTT: free heap size is 159628, minimum 154272
D (13:22:36.063) aMQTT: MQTT_EVENT_PUBLISHED, msg_id=15
D (13:22:36.084) aMQTT: esp_mqtt_client_enqueue successful, msg_id: 16  Topic: SiteID/00003030F93372B8/Fuelpoint/9/Response/Config,  Payload: Code=1, CorData: 6:266842
D (13:22:36.117) aMQTT: INBOX: Topic: SiteID/00003030F93372B8/Fuelpoint/10/Command/Config, Payload: ComPortNo=1/PumpIntNo=10/HoseGrade1=1/HoseUnitPrice1=100.1/ProductDensity1=101/HoseGrade2=2/HoseUnitPrice2=100.2/ProductDensity2=102/HoseGrade3=3/HoseUnitPrice3=100.3/ProductDensity3=103/ConfigMiscControls=00FA/TransMoneyDecPlaces=2/TransVolumeDecPlaces=2/UnitPriceDecPlaces=2/TotalsMoneyDecPlaces=2/TotalsVolumeDecPlaces=2/PumpModeSa=0/PumpModeFcc=1/TaggingConfig=0, RespTopic: SiteID/00003030F93372B8/Fuelpoint/10/Response/Config, CorData: 266843
D (13:22:36.285) aMQTT: esp_mqtt_client_enqueue successful, msg_id: 17  Topic: SiteID/00003030F93372B8/Fuelpoint/10/Response/Config,  Payload: Code=1, CorData: 6:266843
D (13:22:37.099) aMQTT: Event dispatched from event loop base=MQTT_EVENTS, event_id=5
D (13:22:37.101) aMQTT: free heap size is 160460, minimum 154272
D (13:22:37.113) aMQTT: MQTT_EVENT_PUBLISHED, msg_id=16
D (13:22:37.133) aMQTT: Event dispatched from event loop base=MQTT_EVENTS, event_id=5
D (13:22:37.135) aMQTT: free heap size is 160592, minimum 154272
D (13:22:37.146) aMQTT: MQTT_EVENT_PUBLISHED, msg_id=17

